# Como eu faço para pegar um valor no PHP?

Tags: php

Tipo, eu quero pegar tal informação "x" de um json, estando em um array, vou colocar um exemplo aqui:

```
{
   "info":{
      "apistatus":200,
      "apiinfo":"sucesso!",
      "apimessage":"Olá, seja bem vindo ao meu aplicativo!",
      "apiDetalhes":[
         {
            "valor":"esse é um valor X"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Esse json está em uma variável?

Comment: Tipo, igual naquele valor "x" ali no exemplo, eu só quero imprimir ele.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$informacoes = json_decode('{
   "info":{
      "apistatus":200,
      "apiinfo":"sucesso!",
      "apimessage":"Olá, seja bem vindo ao meu aplicativo!",
      "apiDetalhes":[
         {
            "valor":"esse é um valor X"
         }
      ]
   }
}');
?>

<p>A informação "X" é: <?php echo $informacoes->info->apiDetalhes[0]->valor; ?></p>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muito obrigado!